# Quick homework question help (triple Venn diagram questions with maybe)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I have already filled out all the necessary information on the Venn diagram. But some follow up questions are confusing such

find (A and B and maybe C) or

find (A and B but maybe C)

Not sure what these two questions are asking. I have provided an example diagram if it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: wow, I'm not native english speak, but never seen before `A and maybe B`, `A but maybe B` notation for set operations. Do you took  a look in your class notes?

Comment: Where is your Venn diagram that you filled all the information for?

Comment: Maybe $A \text{ and } B \text{ and maybe }C$ and $A \text{ and } B \text{ but maybe }C$ are the same thing.  But maybe not?

Comment: Would have thought that $A \text{ and } B \text{ and maybe } C$ is equal to  $A \text{   and } B \text{ and }(C\cup \overline{C}) = A \text{ and } B$

Comment: Ah, got it (maybe)!  $A \text{ and } B \text{ but maybe } C$ might mean $(A \text{ and } B) \text{ exclusive or } C.$

Comment: Usually when translating from English to logical syntax and and but are considered synonyms.  I don't understand the difference.  Maybe is not a logical term.

Answer (score 0):

English is ambiguous, but a plausible interpretation is the following:

$$A \& B \& (\text{ maybe } C) = A\texttt{ AND }B.$$

$$(A \& B )\text{ but maybe } C = (A \texttt{ AND }B) \texttt{ XOR } C.$$

Comment: can you explain what Maybe means?

Comment: In English, "maybe" means that an event may happen or may not happen.  The phrase "but maybe" seems to imply that if what comes next happens, what came before did not happen.